JQL query get subtasks under issue in specific epic (Jira Server)
I have a specific epic where I want to see all direct issues and their subtasks from. The epic contains a multitude of issues and those issues all have a list of subtasks. How can I create a JQL for this?
I've tried multiple options, however those only work in Jira Cloud and not in Jira Server 9.12 which our company uses. I'd eventually want to save this query as a filter to create a dashboard and keep track of all the work that is done inside the epic.
I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Tjeu


did you try using the "Basic" setting of the query builder in Jira? In "Search Issues", instead of Advanced, select Basic and use the buttons to build your query until you like the result. Then switch back to Advanced and you'll see the query in text (in case you need that). Saving the filter is possible in the same screen.

I used both options, however I can't seem to get the subtasks to show. The epic filter is easy, but getting all subtasks under an issue that has a specific epic seems a little bit more challenging.

from my memory, you can either select "Sub-Task" as an Issue Type (just like Bug, Improvement, New Feature...) or maybe you can add "sub-tasks" as a new column in your view ...

I've found a working solution by adding an and clause with issueFunction in subtasksOf()

Eventually I came to a solution myself by creating three filters;

Get all issues in a specific epic (1234)
"Epic Link" = PROJECT-00001

Get all subtasks under issues that have a specific epic (5678)
issueFunction in subtasksOf("filter = 1234")

Get all the issues and subtasks under a specific epic
filter = 1234 OR filter = 5678



Not sure if you still need this, but please check if my answer is better for it, since it is only one filter, as you originally wanted it :)

issuekey IN childIssuesOf("<epicIssueId>")

You can even do it for more than one epic ancestor:
issuekey IN (childIssuesOf("<epic1IssueId>"), childIssuesOf("<epic2IssueId>"), …)

